# Send message from aura component to React app

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I need to send a message from aura component to react app. This tutorial is exactly what I want:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_sending_messages.htm

However, I need to send the message imediately when the app is loaded. Do we have lifecycle function for aura component or we should I call that function? For example, in react we have componentDidMount

Answer (score 1):

Aura has an `init` event that is fired when when an app or component is initialized, prior to rendering.

```js
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

More info from the official documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:valueInit/documentation

Comment: I update my questions here. Could you take a look to see what's wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65631017/send-message-from-aura-component-to-javascript-application